# Service Worker fetch request from cache so page is not getting updated from new data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service-worker

I am trying to implement the service worker in my AngularJS project for the purpose that if the server(nginx in my case) is restarted then offline page must be displayed for that period but I stuck in the other case.

I have a page where I list the items using GET request, it's fetching response from the server (for the 1 st time), response data being stored in cache BUT my page is updating within regular interval so using this technique the new data are not displaying immediately.

What is wrong in this approach, kindly suggest the better way.

folder structure

```
.
├── app
├── assets
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
├── libs
├── offline.html
└── sw.js
```

below is the code of my service worker file

#### sw.js

```
'use strict';

let appCaches = [{
    name: 'static',
    urls: [
        '/app/',
        '/'
    ]
}, {
    name: 'offline',
    urls: [
        '/offline.html'
    ]
}];

let cacheNames = appCaches.map((cache) => cache.name);

self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
    // console.log('installing');
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys()
        .then((keys) => {
            return Promise.all(appCaches.map((appCache) => {
                console.log(`cache Name:: ${appCache.name}`);
                console.log(`keys:: ${keys}`);
                if (keys.indexOf(appCache.name) === -1) {
                    caches.open(appCache.name).then((cache) => {
                        console.log(`caching ${appCache.name}`);
                        return cache.addAll(appCache.urls);
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log(`found ${appCache.name}`);
                    return Promise.resolve(true);
                }
            })).then(function() {
                // At this point everything has been cached
                return self.skipWaiting();
            });
        }));
});


//Adding `activate` event listener
self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
    // console.info('Event: Activate');
    //Remove old and unwanted caches
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then((keys) => {
            return Promise.all(keys.map((key) => {
                console.log(`activation checking key ${key}`);
                if (cacheNames.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    console.log(`deleting ${key}`);
                    return caches.delete(key);
                }
            }));
        })
    );
});

//-------------------------------------------------------------------
function addToCache(cacheKey, request, response) {
    console.log("addToCache", arguments);
    if (response.ok) {
        var copy = response.clone();
        caches.open(cacheKey).then((cache) => {
            cache.put(request, copy);
        });
        return response;
    }
}

function fetchFromCache(event) {
    console.log("fetchFromCache", arguments);
    return caches.match(event.request).then((response) => {
        if (!response) {
            // A synchronous error that will kick off the catch handler
            throw Error('${event.request.url} not found in cache');
        }
        return response;
    });
}

function offlineResponse(resourceType) {
    console.log("%c offlineResponse::resourceType::" + resourceType, 'color:green');
    if (resourceType === 'content') {
        return caches.match('/offline.html');
    }
    return undefined;
}

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
    var request = event.request;
    var url = new URL(request.url);
    console.log("%curl=>" + url, 'color:red');
    var acceptHeader = request.headers.get('Accept');
    var resourceType = 'static';
    var cacheKey;

    if (acceptHeader.indexOf('text/html') !== -1) {
        resourceType = 'content';
    } else if (acceptHeader.indexOf('image') !== -1) {
        resourceType = 'image';
    }

    // {String} [static|image|content]
    cacheKey = resourceType;

    if (request.method !== 'GET') {
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("resourceType=>", cacheKey);
        if (resourceType === 'content') {
            // Use a network-first strategy.
            console.info("Use a network-first strategy.");
            event.respondWith(
                fetch(request)
                .then((response) => addToCache(cacheKey, request, response))
                .catch(() => fetchFromCache(event))
                .catch(() => offlineResponse(resourceType))
            );
        } else {
            // Use a cache-first strategy.
            console.info("Use a cache-first strategy.");
            event.respondWith(
                fetchFromCache(event)
                .catch(() => fetch(request))
                .then((response) => addToCache(cacheKey, request, response))
                .catch(() => offlineResponse(resourceType))
            );
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `key` for the resource in cache is `request` (Since you are using `cache.put(request, copy)` in `addToCache` function), but you are retrieving it using `url` (e.g `/offline.html` in `offlineResponse` function). You should match with `request` in `cache`.

Comment: I have added *offlne.html* in `install` event ( as URL name)  that's why. can you please post the updated code in the answer.  still not clear what you want to say to change,

Comment: @diEcho Why is this answer accepted if it seemingly does not resolve your problem?

Comment: Yes. You are right but there is not any other answer and this is not exactly the solution but it gives me a path to handle the issue.