# Service Worker fetch event will not fire without next refresh

Tags: google-chrome, service-worker

I'm learning how to use service worker, my problem is that when clicking the button to `fetch()` some file when the page is loaded for first time didn't fire any `fetch` event, but after manually refresh the page then clicking the button again, the `fetch` event get fired as expected

Please guide how to fix this
thanks

> Chrome: 60

*service-worker.js*

```
self.addEventListener('install', event => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open('XXX')
            .then(cache => {
                cache.allAll([ ... ])
            })
    )
})

self.addEventListener('activate', event => {
    console.log('ready')
})

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    console.log('fetch')
})
```

*index.html*

```
<body>
    <button id="btn" class="button">Click</button>

    <script>
    (() => {
        document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
            fetch(' ... ')
                .then(res => {
                    return res.json()
                })
                .then(res => {
                    console.log(res)
                })
        })

        if (!('serviceWorker' in navigator)) {
            console.log('Service Worker is not supported')

            return
        }

        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/service-worker.js')
            .then((registration) => {
                console.log('Sevice Worker has been registered')
            })
    })()
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably need a self.clients.claim() to activate the service-worker asap.

```
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(self.clients.claim());
});
```

see: [What is the use of `self.Clients.claim()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41009167/what-is-the-use-of-self-clients-claim)

Comment: i tried this still fetch not getting fired in page load

Comment: This is not working, the fetch event is still not called.